# arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--build-id’

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, compiler-errors, linux-kernel

I am trying to compile a simple module kernel with an ARM CROSS_COMPILE

```
    obj-m := hello_dkm.o
    default:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
    clean:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$$PWD clean
```

I have got the error below in the shell:

```
    make -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS = $$PWD
       LD /drv-hello-world/src/impl/built-in.o
       CC [M] /drv-hello-world/src/impl/hello_dkm.o
       Building modules, stage 2.
       MODPOST 1 modules
       CC   ~/drv-hello-world/src/impl/hello_dkm.mod.o
       LD [M]  ~/drv-hello-world/src/impl/hello_dkm.ko
       arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--
       build-id’

    my comments: --build-id is an LD flag added in the kernel makefile as below:
   # Use --build-id when available. (Linux Makefile - line ~613)
   LDFLAGS_BUILD_ID = $(patsubst -Wl$(comma)%,%,\
              $(call cc-ldoption, -Wl$(comma)--build-id,)) #--build-id
   KBUILD_LDFLAGS_MODULE += $(LDFLAGS_BUILD_ID)
   LDFLAGS_vmlinux += $(LDFLAGS_BUILD_ID)
```

Appendix

```
    # The C compiler.
    CC = arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
    # The linker.
    LD = arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld
    ARCH = arm
    kernel target: Linux socfpga_cyclone5 3.7.0 #1 SMP Thu Apr 25 18:36:58 CDT 2013 armv7l GNU/Linux
    host : Opensuse linux 4.4.36-5-default
```

Best,

```
    EDIT solved: I had to modify the LD def to $(CROSS_COMPILE)ld
```

Comment: Did you tried `make clean` before compilation? (For the case if you have compiled the module with *host* gcc firstly).

Comment: thanks for your quick response, yes I did it, but always got the same error, I even tried to compile into a new project directory...

Comment: Do you have C++ code in there (Or filenames ending in a capital .C or .cpp, or .cc)  ? arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ is being invoked - which is pretty odd for a kernel module.

Comment: No, actually I have a simple hello world driver: hello.c  #Source files: hello.c
  
        #include <linux/module.h>
        #include <linux/kernel.h>
        int init_module(void)
        {
       printk(KERN_INFO "init_module() called\n");
       return 0;
        }
        void cleanup_module(void)
        {
        printk(KERN_INFO "cleanup_module() called\n");
        }
        ----- END--------

Comment: source file = hello_dkm.c

Comment: # The C++ compiler.
        CXX = arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
        # The archive builder.
        AR = arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar #AR = arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-ar 
        # The archive indexer.
        RANLIB = arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-ranlib
        # The ELF reader.
        READELF = arm-linux-gnueabihf-readelf
        # The linker.
        LD = arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ 
        STRIP = arm-linux-gnueabihf-strip
        # The C compiler. 
        CC = arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc